# Tools for analysis of transportation in maps

Tags: python, data-visualization, maps, geo-location

I have a very large database with latitude and longitude of taxis. I want to make routes and plot these in maps to make analysis and heat maps, and I want tools for this.

I had tried the [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), but I had too much trouble to install in the server. I want to discover new tools like python library or another to help me in this issue.

Comment: Perhaps [Postgres](http://postgresql.org), [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/).